# Toffoli gate not included in the normalizer group

Tags: error-correction, stabilizer-state

While reviewing the stabilizer formalism in Nielsen and Chuang, I could not understand why the Toffoli and the $\frac{\pi}{8}$ cannot be described as normalizers, even though they map Pauli group elements to other Pauli group elements. I've attached the screenshot from Nielsen and Chuang as reference below.

Thanks

[image: Normalizer exception N&C]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing is that while each of those gates maps some of the Pauli operators to other Pauli operators (e.g. the left-hand side of 10.92), other Pauli operators (e.g. right-hand side of 10.92) do not get mapped to single Pauli operators but, instead, a linear combination of different Pauli operators: $(X+Y)/\sqrt{2}$ is not in the Pauli group. You need it to be true *for all* Pauli operators.